# OpenId' PAPE equivalent for facebook connect

Tags: security, facebook, openid

I'm using OpenId and Facebook Connect to allow users to idendify themselves on my website.

For sensitive operations (like changing OpenId) I'm using the PAPE extension of OpenId ( http://openid.net/specs/openid-provider-authentication-policy-extension-1_0-01.html ) with the option `max_auth_age=0` to force the user to identify himself once again at his OpenId provider.

What I would like to prevent is : if someone let his session open on facebook on a public computer then nothing damageable can be done on my website.

PAPE allow that, but what can I do for Facebook connect ?
And I don't want to log out the user from Facebook and then ask him to log in again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this TODO list](http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/27250569/Future-OpenID-Technical-Requirements), PAPE needs still be added to OAuth2.

Comment: With the draft from 2007 and the fact that google supports it I thought it was part of OpenId. So basically it's still not a part of OpenId spécification ?

Comment: I thought you were asking about Facebook. Facebook doesn't support OpenID at all - so it seems irrelevant whether PAPE is part of OpenID or not (but it's the same as it always was: an extension that providers (of *OpenID*) may provide).

Comment: Yes I was asking about facebook, for an equivalent for PAPE. I know it's not OpenId. But still it's interresting to know that's it's just an extension that may (or not) be provided.